# Optimization Techniques For Rendering Microsoft Teams Conversations From Graph API

Tags: performance, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We plan to integrate with microsoft teams by calling graph api's and developing our own UI's to allow team discussions/chats. We would be making graph api calls to fetch the threaded discussions from various channels and display them in our application. The UI's look similar to microsoft teams.

We are facing performance problems when calling microsoft graph api's for fetching threads of a particular channel. For e.g. It takes around 5-6 secs for fetching top 20 threads and this increases as the number of concurrent users increases. Since we cannot break this api call into multiple parallel calls (that doesn't help too at times), I would like to get inputs on best practices for building such applications based on Microsoft Teams.

Note that we do not plan to integrate our application inside Microsoft Teams as a tab instead we want to provide collaboration capabilities inside our application using office 365 teams app.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [Teams Graph APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview) are in Beta version. Before we move to production (v1) the APIs will be optimized for performance.

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have an estimate as to when the production release is planned? It is important to know this timeline so that we can plan our application releases accordingly. If the production release is going to take time (more than a quarter for e.g.) are there any recommended best practices to workaround this performance problem?